# how to display and select shapefile polygons in mapwingis

Tags: vb.net, mapwingis

l am developing a GIS_desktop application with VB.NET and MapWinGIS.When l load a shapefile into the application,it is displaying  blocks instead of the actual polygons[displayed shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEZGn.jpg).The shapefile is supposed to display the polygons as shown in the attached image[original shapefile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMvUD.jpg)

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Which version of MapWinGIS are you using? The latest stable version can be found at https://github.com/MapWindow/MapWinGIS/releases

Can you share your shapefile? At the new MapWindow/MapWinGIS forum you can upload files: https://mapwindow.discourse.group/c/mapwingis